# How to check if a number is in a interval

Tags: python, coding-style, range, intervals

Suppose I got:

```
first_var = 1
second_var = 5
interval = 2
```

I want an interval from second_var like `second_var ± interval` (from 3 to 7).
I wank to check if first_var is in that interval.
So in this specific case I want `False`
If `first_var = 4`, I want `True`

I can do this:

```
if (first_var > second_var-interval) and (first_var < second_var+interval):
  #True
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: If your `first_var` is always an integer, you can just use range/xrange objects for Python 3.x and Python 2.x respectively and combine them with the `in` operator for speedy membership tests that read like English. Example: `4 in range(3, 8)` Note that the stop parameter is non-inclusive for the range, but you can assign the range to any variable that has a more descriptive name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use a class with [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) to represent the interval:

```
class Interval(object):
    def __init__(self, middle, deviation):
        self.lower = middle - abs(deviation)
        self.upper = middle + abs(deviation)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return self.lower <= item <= self.upper
```

Then I define a function `interval` to simplify the syntax:

```
def interval(middle, deviation):
    return Interval(middle, deviation)
```

Then we can call it as follows:

```
>>> 8 in interval(middle=6, deviation=2)
True

>>> 8 in interval(middle=6, deviation=1)
False
```

With Python 2 this solution is more efficient than using `range` or `xrange` as they don't implement `__contains__` and they have to search for a matching value.

Python 3 is smarter and `range` is a generating object which is efficient like `xrange`, but also implements `__contains__` so it doesn't have to search for a valid value. `xrange` doesn't exist in Python 3.

This solution also works with floats.

Also, note, if you use `range` you need to be careful of off-by-1 errors. Better to encapsulate it, if you're going to be doing it more than once or twice.

Comment: Note that this is not going to be more efficient than Python 3.x's range (it use simple math for `__contains__` too). Try `5555555555555 in range(99999999999999)` in your 3.x REPL and you'll see that it returns `True` very quickly :) But this is a good solution because it handles floats, and can also have a better `__str__` than range objects. It's also better in every way than Python 2.x range and xrange.

Answer (score 14):

You can use math-like sequence as Python supports that

```
if (second_var-interval < first_var < second_var+interval):
     # True
```

Note that comments in python begin with a `#`

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambdas:

```
lmd = lambda fv, sv, inval: print('True') if \
    sv - inval < fv < sv + inval else print('False')
```

and use it like:

```
lmd(first_var, second_var, interval)
```

but it's a little bit long!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (first_var in range(second_var-interval, second_var+interval+1)):
    #Do something
```

Comment: This only checks for equality at the two extremes which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @martineau Wrong, it also works for integers in between, but it only works if first_var is an integer, not if it is a float!